# Mysql pool connection error with glassfish/payara server

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Ping Connection Pool failed for MySQL Pool. Connection could not be allocated because: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. Please check the server.log for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to give solution here as I already read and view many solutions regarding this error but not anyone of them is good for me.

So please follow the step by step process:-

1. Download and Install Glassfish/Payara Server.
2. Download and Install latest mysql.
3. Install it as full and in mysql folder you can find an Connector j folder.
   from there copy the executable jar file and paste it into two folders.

   - glassfish5\glassfish\lib
   - glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib
4. Now restart the server from netbeans.
5. Open admin console and then goto JDBC and then select jdbc connection pool
   [image]

   Add particular property :-

   - Database name
   - Password
   - port :- 3306
   - ServerName :- localhost
   - Url :-jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
   - User
     6.Enable ping
6. save

Best of luck

Answer (score 3):

In my case this problem got fixed by adding "**useSSL**" to the pool properties and setting it to **false**.

Comment: Just to clarify to novices like me, ensure that either the URL is used or the individual properties

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for payara 5 and Mysql 8

Select Mysql 8 as  Database Driver Vendor

[image]

When you try create the connection pool remove all default propierties and write the  properties manually as shown in the below image, something is wrong with default properties becuase the connection can't be reached so to avoid issues please remove them and try add them manually.

[image]

Note: don't forget add your mysql connector to

- glassfish5\glassfish\lib
- glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to connect to MySQL on cloud (Ex. Azure MySQL) make sure the SSL enforcement is off in addition to above and setting useSSL = false.

[Azure MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LRLc.jpg)